# Problem with locationListener

Tags: android, google-maps, locationlistener

The application doesnt point to where I am at..here is what i have done:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mv=(MapView) findViewById (R.id.mapView);
    mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   // mv.setSatellite(true);
    mv.setStreetView(true);


lmanager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    llistener=new MyLocationListener();
    lmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, llistener);

}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(location!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed: "+location.getLatitude()+" lang: "+ location.getLongitude() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // no toast is shown
        }
         p=new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()*1E6), (int)(location.getLongitude()*1E6));
        mapC.animateTo(p);
        mapC.setZoom(18);//no zooming happens
    }



@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

To my manifest I added both of these:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all sorry for poor english. when the location was changed and you set the value into the map you need to invalidate the map using the invalidate() method of MapView class so you can get the updated value on the map

```
mapC.animateTo(p);
mapC.setZoom(18);
mv.invalidate();
```

as well as add after you set the value at initial time set into the map like

```
mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mv.setStreetView(true);
mv.invalidate();
```

Comment: The locationListener doesnt even get triggered..I put a message inside and nothing happens

Comment: a textmessage pop ups here: onProviderDisabled(String provider) {..why is my provider disabled?

Comment: onLocationChanged doesn't get triggered unless you have a valid GPS fix.  Try running Google maps first to see if you have a valid location.

Comment: i have run your code it's perfectly i think you getting problem with the gps value of setting

Comment: I get something, but i get now:08-31 12:57:13.654: ERROR/MapActivity(4275): Couldn't get connection factory client